# Delay an application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, delay

Hey I am new to Visual Studio 2012 (I'm using vb.net) and is there any way to delay the macro for a certain amount of time?
I have tried "Application.Wait" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you're only using a single thread...

```
Imports System.Threading 'Credit to @Force - thank you

Thread.Sleep(ms)
```

I'm not sure if you're looking for something that simple or not.

---

Or you can add:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

And simply call Sleep(ms).

'ms' being the number of milliseconds you want to wait (1000ms = 1 second).

Comment: In order to use the Thread.Sleep(ms) you will need to add that namespace to your code: Imports System.Threading

Answer (score 2):

Unless you want to freeze your UI, it's not a good practice to sleep the main thread.
Instead put your delay in a separate thread, and delay only on the separate thread. Better yet, put some loader/progress indicator to let the user know, that some background process is running.